# Modifying each item of a List in java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

I'm just starting to work with lists in java. I'm wondering what the recommended method to modify each element of a list would be?

I've been able to get it done with both the following methods, but they both seem fairly unelegant. Is there any better way to get this done in java? And is any of the below methods recommended over the other, or are both on the same level?

```
//Modifying with foreach
for (String each : list)
{
    list.set(list.indexOf(each), each+ " blah");
}

//Modifying with for
for (ListIterator<String> i = list.listIterator(); i.hasNext(); i.next()) 
{
    i.next();
    list.set(i.nextIndex()-1, i.previous() + " blah yadda");
}
```

Comment: @chrylis: They're not *structurally* modifying it though. I believe you can normally replace elements in a list without invalidating an iterator... at least for ArrayList, for example. I could be wrong, of course :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet I think it's actually a problem when you're doing for each, you cannot change the size of the list you're going through.

Comment: @Lucas: Yes, that's typically it. Which isn't the case here, of course.

Comment: Sure, I was just making a point :)

Comment: Will the above code work ? I think its ConcurrentModificationException. Modifying the same list which is responsible for loop..!!

Comment: @VinayVeluri: I did try both pieces of code out before posting and they both worked. I'm assuming ConcurrentModificationException would only arise if I was trying to modify the number of elements while in the loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change items in a list of string in java8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757764/how-to-change-items-in-a-list-of-string-in-java8)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The second version would be better. Internally they are the same in the end, but the second actually allows you to modify the list, while the first one will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

But then you are using the Iterator in a wrong way. Here is how you do it correctly:

```
for (final ListIterator<String> i = list.listIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
  final String element = i.next();
  i.set(element + "yaddayadda");
}
```

The iterator is the one that needs to modify the list as it is the only one that knows how to do that properly without getting confused about the list elements and order.

**Edit:** Because I see this in all comments and the other answers:

**Why you should not use list.get, list.set and list.size in a loop**

There are many collections in the Java collections framework, each on optimized for specific needs. Many people use the ArrayList, which internally uses an array. This is fine as long as the amount of elements does not change much over time and has the special benefit that get, set and size are **constant time operations on this specific type of list**.

There are however other list types, where this is not true. For example if you have a list that constantly grows and/or shrinks, it is much better to use a LinkedList, because in contrast to the ArrayList add(element) is a constant time operation, but add(index, element), get(index) and remove(index) **are not!**

To get the position of the specific index, the list needs to be traversed from the first/last till the specific element is found. So if you do that in a loop, this is equal to the following pseudo-code:

```
for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); ++index) {
  Element e = get( (for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) { if (i == index) return element; else element = nextElement(); }) );
}
```

The Iterator is an abstract way to traverse a list and therefore it can ensure that the traversal is done in an optimal way for each list. Test show that there is little time difference between using an iterator and get(i) for an ArrayList, but a huge time difference (in favor for the iterator) on a LinkedList.

Comment: I don't believe the first one *will* throw a ConcurrentModificationException actually - at least not in any list where just setting an element counts as a non-structural change, which would be most of them. `LinkedList` *does* have constant-time `size()` by the way (IIRC - I can't check easily right now)- but not `get` or` set`.

Comment: Working with believes is not a good idea, give it a try instead. ;)
You will notice that most lists actually do throw an exception.

Comment: I can't this instant, but will do so in an hour. And "most" isn't the same as "will" either :) IIRC `ArrayList` (which is the most common list used, IMO) doesn't count `set` as a structural change.

Comment: @TwoThe Thank you! This was very helpful. Though I do note that I tried out both pieces of code before posting (with an ArrayList) and both worked, so as JonSkeet said ConcurrentModificationException is not being thrown for ArrayList at least.

Comment: "To get the size of this list, what happens internally is that the entire list is traversed from the first to the last element and the elements are counted." - No, that's not what happens for `LinkedList`. At least not in the code I'm looking at: `public int size() { return size; }`. Which implementation are you looking at which *does* do that?

Comment: List size is known only because it internally optimizes the issue away. Point for you. ;) The javadoc is more concrete on what is problematic.

Comment: @Exception: Your code is probably faulty. Try the following: `for (String s : list) { list.add("Test"); }` on a non-empty list of String of your choice. Immediately crashes on ArrayList and LinkedList (and probably more).

Comment: @TwoThe: That's using `add`. This code *isn't* using `add`, it's using `set`. As I said before, it's not a structural change. Claiming the code is "probably faulty" when it's doing the same thing as the OP's code is a bit odd...

Answer (score 11):

EDIT: **If** you know that `size()`, `get(index)` and `set(index, value)` are all constant time operations for the operations you're using (e.g. for `ArrayList`), I would personally just skip the iterators in this case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    list.set(i, list.get(i) + " blah");
}
```

Your first approach is inefficient and potentially incorrect (as `indexOf` may return the wrong value - it will return the *first* match). Your second approach is very confusing - the fact that you call `next()` twice and `previous` once makes it hard to understand in my view.

Any approach using `List.set(index, value)` will be inefficient for a list which doesn't have constant time indexed write access, of course. As TwoThe noted, using `ListIterator.set(value)` is much better. TwoThe's approach of using a `ListIterator` is a better general purpose approach.

That said, another alternative in many cases would be to change your design to project one list to another instead - either as a view or materially. When you're not *changing* the list, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: This will be extremely inefficient if you use it on a list which has no constant time operator for size and get, like the commonly used LinkedList. Better to use the iterator in all cases.

Comment: @TwoThe: Using `ListIterator.set`, that makes sense - but the code in the question would still be O(n^2) though.

Comment: No it would be O(n), because you have one complete iteration over the list, but manipulate those elements immediately. That is: the iterator already knows where to do the change and does not need to look-up the position again. See my answer below.

Comment: @TwoThe: Doh, misreading stuff... going to delete this, as I'm in a lunch meeting and need to concentrate...

Comment: @TwoThe: Coming back to it - no, the original code would still be O(n^2). The outer loop is O(n), but calling `list.set(index, value)` inside the loop makes it O(n^2) when `list.set(index, value)` is O(n) as per `LinkedList`.

Comment: That is why I said you should _not_ do list.set() but iterator.set()

Comment: @TwoThe: Yes, but that's also why I specifically said: "The code in the question would still be O(n^2)" which you disagreed with. If you're using `ListIterator.set`, that's not the code in the question, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Internally there in `Iterator` for `for-each` implementation. So there is no deference between these two cases. But if you trying to modify element it will `throws` `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: The two pieces of code are pretty significantly different, actually. It's not like one is just a rewrite of the other to use the iterator explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine working this way

```
    String desiredInvoice="abc-123";
    long desiredAmount=1500;

    for (ListIterator<MyPurchase> it = input.getMyPurchaseList().listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        MyPurchase item = it.next();
        if (item.getInvoiceNo().equalsIgnoreCase(desiredInvoice)) {
            item.setPaymentAmount(desiredAmount);
            it.set(item);
            break;
        }
     }
```