# how to change items in a list of string in java8

Tags: java, list, java-8

I want to change all items in `list`.
What is the correct way to do it with `java8`?

```
public class TestIt {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add("AB");
    l.add("A");
    l.add("AA");
    l.forEach(x -> x = "b" + x);
    System.out.println(l);
}

}
```

Comment: Remember that everything valid in Java 7 is also valid in Java 8. Thus there are multiple correct ways.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-).

> Replaces each element of this list with the result of applying the
>   operator to that element.

```
ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("AB","A","AA"));
l.replaceAll(x -> "b" + x);
System.out.println(l);
```

Output:

```
[bAB, bA, bAA]
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexis C. for the answer.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to use streams, you can do something like that:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("AB","A","AA"));
l = l.stream().map(x -> "b" + x).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(l);
```

Output:

```
[bAB, bA, bAA]
```

Of course it is better to use [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) if you want to change all elements of a list but using streams enables you to also apply filters or to parallel easily. `replaceAll` also modifies the list and throws an exception when the list is unmodifiable, whereas `collect`creates a new list.

Comment: Could you also explain, why it is better to use Streams? Or explain, what the difference is?

Comment: I added a comment. The idea was to show another way how it can be implemented using new Java 8 functionality. As immibis said commenting the question there are multiple correct ways how to achieve what was asked.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the further explanation! That's what I wanted to achieve :)