# How do you write a program to convert degrees to radians from a list in java

Tags: java, oop, math, degrees, radians

So the program needs to do the following:

Replace the elements of a list of angles specified in degrees to convert them to their radians equivalent, and the size of the list remains unchanged.

This is what I have and tried so far:

```
public static void toRadians(List<Double> t) {
    for(int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
        Math.toRadians(t.get(i));

    } 
}
```

I'm pretty much stuck as it does not work for some reason.

Comment: The instructions say: "Replace the elements of a list". I see the code reading a value from the list (using get()), but I don't see any code replacing a value in the list. Read the javadoc of List: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: If you want to return a list with radians, then you want to change the return type of `toRadians` from `void` to `List<Double>`, and actually create and return the new list. If you want to change values in the list that you pass to `toRadians` method, then you probably should call [List#set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-).

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I had to set the value back into the list.

Comment: Accessing with `get(...)` and `set(...)` is super slow if it is not an `ArrayList`. I"d suggest going an approach that is fast for all lists, by using its `ListIterator`.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

```
public static void toRadians(List<Double> t) {
    for(int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
        t.set(i, Math.toRadians(t.get(i)));
    }
}
```

As you use [`List#get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) to get a value of element with index `i`. You have to use a setter method, which is [`List#set(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-), to assign the value to element with index `i`.

Comment: doesn't return anything

Comment: As it's void function, it shouldn't return anything. We use `.set()` function so it edits the numbers directly for the list.
So, do you want to have a copy from the list, then editing it and return the list back ? or what type of return you really wants ?

Comment: OP originally had a return type as a requirement

Comment: Or at least that's what I thought this meant: `By the way it has to return type.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) to transform elements in a list:

```
public static void toRadians(List<Double> degrees) {
    degrees.replaceAll(Math::toRadians);
}
```

Or if you don't want to change the original list, you can use [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), to create a new list with elements transformed:

```
public static List<Double> toRadians(List<Double> degrees) {
    return degrees.stream()
                  .map(Math::toRadians)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: You should prefer the lambda implementation.

Comment: @duffymo - Do you mean it's preferred to use `(x) -> Math.toRadians(x)` over `Math::toRadians`? Why?

Comment: No, I mean I prefer your answer to the ones that loop over collections.  Yours is cleaner.

Comment: "You" refers to the OP, not "ArtuX"

Comment: Oh! Great - Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can complete the task with [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000443/modifying-each-item-of-a-list-in-java) for using a `ListIterator`:

```
public static List<Double> convertToRadians(List<Double> t) {

    for (final ListIterator<Double> iterator = t.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        final Double element = iterator.next();
        iterator.set(Math.toRadians(element));
    }
    return t;
}
```

A succinct way to do this using Java 8+ (but with slightly different mechanics) would be:

```
public static List<Double> convertToRadians(List<Double> t) {

    t.replaceAll(Math::toRadians);
    return t;
}
```

For your exercise, you will no doubt want to look at the time complexity for each way to complete this task and mutability, and in particular the time complexity to just adding and removing each element in the list.